# Unable to switch Desktop Environment/GUI's at login page

Tags: 12.10, login-screen, desktop-environments

I'm unable to switch to the Gnome Environment from the default Ubuntu user login page. The list comes up, but when I click Gnome, it doesn't select the gnome enviromnent. When I click back to see the username, Ubuntu is still the default.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the little arrow to click back to the username.  Select the "OK" button at the bottom of the session list (Ubuntu, Gnome, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if your list of available environments is too long, the OK button is off the bottom of the screen.  Hit tab several times, until you think you're at the bottom of the list, and then hit it one more time.  Then press 'Enter'.