# Limited Desktop environments seen at logon

Tags: login, login-screen, desktop-environments

Whenever I log on and I want to change my desktop environment.I click on the button to change my environment.I have many desktop environments almost 10-12.It is arranged in alphabetical order.So U comes towards the end.I want to use Ubuntu desktop environment but I am not able to scroll down the list.Why is this so,can I use Ubuntu now or not?

Comment: mmmmmh, might be a bug. can you supply us a screenshot?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/257834/248158

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/286648/248158

Comment: How can I add a snapshot here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround and **not** final solution:

- Log into an available desktop environment
- Open a file manager
- Go to `/usr/share/xsessions`
- Look for the desktop environment you want to always have visible
- Use right-click and open that entry with a GUI text editor *just to see what the real name of that entry is* and **not** for editing. The name should be `<something>.desktop` and should be visible in the title bar of the editor window.
- Then, open a terminal and run `sudo nano <something>.desktop` which you got from previous step.
- Look at the line beginning with `Name=`; this is mostly second line. For example, you may see `Name=Xubuntu Session`
- Modify that to `Name=AAA-Xubuntu Session`.
- Save your changes and log out.
- Now, the very first entry in your choice of desktop environments will be `AAA-Xubuntu Session`.

Of course, this is not a final solution but just one way to let you rearrange the list :)